# Why does my Bazel test report failure when all individual tests are passing?

Tags: googletest, bazel

When running my unit test (gtest) through Bazel, I'm seeing a failure reported. However, the logs indicate that my test is running successfully and passing.

Other tests in my project are passing and the only difference between the deviant test and the others is that the deviant test is multithreaded.

I've run the test binary found in `bazel-bin` by itself and it passes and returns successfully.

Bazel version:

```
Build label: 0.26.0
Build target: bazel-out/k8-opt/bin/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/bazel/BazelServer_deploy.jar
Build time: Tue May 28 08:35:14 2019 (1559032514)
Build timestamp: 1559032514
Build timestamp as int: 1559032514
```

The relevant block in my `BUILD` file:

```
cc_test(
  name = "DBControllerIntegration",
  srcs = ["dbcontroller_integration_test.cc"],
  deps = [
    "//src:db_ctl_lib",
    "//test/mocks:sstable_mock_lib",
    "@boost//:filesystem",
    "@com_google_protobuf//:protobuf",
    "@glog//:glog",
    "@googletest//:gtest_main",
  ],
  copts = ["-std=c++17"],
)
```

Bazel test failure output:

```
>> bazel test //test:DBControllerIntegration --test_output=errors
INFO: Invocation ID: ccca8fa7-27a5-4c8c-badf-3f342934e4e5
INFO: Analysed target //test:DBControllerIntegration (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 test target...
FAIL: //test:DBControllerIntegration (see /home/tallen/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tallen/f087948e065d612174d90a43a5740198/execroot/diodb/bazel-out/k8-dbg/testlogs/test/DBControllerIntegration/test.log)
INFO: From Testing //test:DBControllerIntegration:
==================== Test output for //test:DBControllerIntegration:
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from DBControllerIntegrationTest
[ RUN      ] DBControllerIntegrationTest.Basic

... <omitting my application's logs> ...

[       OK ] DBControllerIntegrationTest.Basic (4000 ms)
[----------] 1 test from DBControllerIntegrationTest (4000 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (4001 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
================================================================================
Target //test:DBControllerIntegration up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/test/DBControllerIntegration
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.706s, Critical Path: 4.57s
INFO: 1 process: 1 processwrapper-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
//test:DBControllerIntegration                                           FAILED in 4.6s
  /home/tallen/.cache/bazel/_bazel_tallen/f087948e065d612174d90a43a5740198/execroot/diodb/bazel-out/k8-dbg/testlogs/test/DBControllerIntegration/test.log

INFO: Build completed, 1 test FAILED, 2 total actions
```

Running the test binary by itself:

```
>> ./bazel-bin/test/DBControllerIntegration
Running main() from gmock_main.cc
[==========] Running 1 test from 1 test case.
[----------] Global test environment set-up.
[----------] 1 test from DBControllerIntegrationTest
[ RUN      ] DBControllerIntegrationTest.Basic

... <omitting my application's logs> ...

[       OK ] DBControllerIntegrationTest.Basic (4001 ms)
[----------] 1 test from DBControllerIntegrationTest (4001 ms total)

[----------] Global test environment tear-down
[==========] 1 test from 1 test case ran. (4001 ms total)
[  PASSED  ] 1 test.
```

I would expect the Bazel test result to be reported as passing since the actual test is passing, but I'm seeing the test as failed.

Comment: Run with `--cache_test_results=no` - I guess some chaced test leads to this error

Comment: Interesting, I'm now seeing a segfault in Bazel:
`external/bazel_tools/tools/test/test-setup.sh: line 310:    14 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) "${TEST_PATH}" "$@"  2>&1`

Other posts that have this segfault seem to have downgraded Bazel, but that's not really a resolution. I'm updating the post with my Bazel version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was resolved when gracefully terminating all threads spawned by my project.